# How to add to an existing XML file in VB.net?

Tags: xml, vb.net

new to XML and having trouble adding in new nodes to an existing XML file.

Here's how the XML file looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Users>
  <UserName-1>
    <Private-1>
      <PrivateFtpAccountId-1>11111</PrivateFtpAccountId-1>
      <PrivatePassword-1>test1</PrivatePassword-1>
    </Private-1>
    <Public-1>
      <PublicFtpAccountId-1>22222</PublicFtpAccountId-1>
      <PublicPassword-1>test2</PublicPassword-1>
    </Public-1>
  </UserName-1>
  <UserName-2>
    <Private-2>
      <PrivateFtpAccountId-2>33333</PrivateFtpAccountId-2>
      <PrivatePassword-2>test3</PrivatePassword-2>
    </Private-2>
    <Public-2>
      <PublicFtpAccountId-2>44444</PublicFtpAccountId-2>
      <PublicPassword-2>test4</PublicPassword-2>
    </Public-2>
  </UserName-2>
</Users>
```

I want to add in these following the last grouping.

```
<UserName-3>
    <Private-3>
      <PrivateFtpAccountId-3>55555</PrivateFtpAccountId-3>
      <PrivatePassword-3>test5</PrivatePassword-3>
    </Private-3>
    <Public-3>
      <PublicFtpAccountId-3>66666</PublicFtpAccountId-3>
      <PublicPassword-3>test6</PublicPassword-3>
    </Public-3>
</UserName-3>
```

After running my code below I produce this XML file (I'm replacing the original):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Users>
  <UserName-1>
    <Private-1>
      <PrivateFtpAccountId-1>11111</PrivateFtpAccountId-1>
      <PrivatePassword-1>test1</PrivatePassword-1>
    </Private-1>
    <Public-1>
      <PublicFtpAccountId-1>22222</PublicFtpAccountId-1>
      <PublicPassword-1>test2</PublicPassword-1>
    </Public-1>
  </UserName-1>
  <UserName-2>
    <Private-2>
      <PrivateFtpAccountId-2>33333</PrivateFtpAccountId-2>
      <PrivatePassword-2>test3</PrivatePassword-2>
    </Private-2>
    <Public-2>
      <PublicFtpAccountId-2>44444</PublicFtpAccountId-2>
      <PublicPassword-2>test4</PublicPassword-2>
    </Public-2>
  </UserName-2>
  <Private-3>
    <PrivateFtpAccountId-3>55555</PrivateFtpAccountId-3>
    <PublicFtpAccountId-3>test5</PublicFtpAccountId-3>
  </Private-3>
  <Public-3>
    <PublicFtpAccountId-3>66666</PublicFtpAccountId-3>
    <PublicFtpAccountId-3>test6</PublicFtpAccountId-3>
  </Public-3>
</Users>
```

But having trouble getting the username tags in and the other tags to go between them
as shown above. I tried a few things with no success. Those "things" are not in the code any longer.

My code in a console app:

```
    Dim strPrivateRoot As XmlNode
    Dim strPublicRoot As XmlNode
    Dim strUserNameRoot As XmlNode
    Dim strElementPrivateFtpAcctId As XmlNode
    Dim strElementPrivatePassword As XmlNode
    Dim strElementPublicFtpAcctId As XmlNode
    Dim strElementPublicPassword As XmlNode
    Dim strId As String
    Dim strPrivateFtpAcctId As String
    Dim strPrivatePassword As String
    Dim strPublicFtpAcctId As String
    Dim strPublicPassword As String

    strPrivateFtpAcctId = "55555"
    strPrivatePassword = "test5"
    strPublicFtpAcctId = "66666"
    strPublicPassword = "test6"

    ' Can be any Id.
    strId = "3"

    ' Create a new XmlDocument class, and use the Load method to load the XML file.
    Dim myXmlDocument As New XmlDocument()

    '' The XmlDocument class represents the XML document and has a Load method to load the document from a file, stream, or an XmlReader.
    '' So load in the XML file.
    myXmlDocument.Load("MyGoodXMLforadding.xml")

    ' Grab the root to start adding after.
    Dim objRoot = myXmlDocument.DocumentElement

    ' For Private:
    strPrivateRoot = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("Private-" & strId)

    strElementPrivateFtpAcctId = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("PrivateFtpAccountId-" & strId)
    strElementPrivateFtpAcctId.InnerText = strPrivateFtpAcctId
    strPrivateRoot.AppendChild(strElementPrivateFtpAcctId)

    strElementPrivatePassword = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("PublicFtpAccountId-" & strId)
    strElementPrivatePassword.InnerText = strPrivatePassword
    strPrivateRoot.AppendChild(strElementPrivatePassword)

    myXmlDocument.DocumentElement.AppendChild(strPrivateRoot)

    ' For Public:
    strPublicRoot = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("Public-" & strId)

    strElementPublicFtpAcctId = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("PublicFtpAccountId-" & strId)
    strElementPublicFtpAcctId.InnerText = strPublicFtpAcctId
    strPublicRoot.AppendChild(strElementPublicFtpAcctId)

    strElementPublicPassword = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("PublicFtpAccountId-" & strId)
    strElementPublicPassword.InnerText = strPublicPassword
    strPublicRoot.AppendChild(strElementPublicPassword)

    myXmlDocument.DocumentElement.AppendChild(strPublicRoot)

    ' Save in place.
    myXmlDocument.Save("MyGoodXMLforadding.xml")
    Console.WriteLine("The XML file was saved successfully.")
```

Answer (score 1):

XElement has methods for reading and writing files.

Once loaded the code would be

```
'orig = XElement.Load("FILENAMES_HERE")
Dim orig As XElement =
  <Users>
    <UserName-1>
      <Private-1>
        <PrivateFtpAccountId-1>11111</PrivateFtpAccountId-1>
        <PrivatePassword-1>test1</PrivatePassword-1>
      </Private-1>
      <Public-1>
        <PublicFtpAccountId-1>22222</PublicFtpAccountId-1>
        <PublicPassword-1>test2</PublicPassword-1>
      </Public-1>
    </UserName-1>
    <UserName-2>
      <Private-2>
        <PrivateFtpAccountId-2>33333</PrivateFtpAccountId-2>
        <PrivatePassword-2>test3</PrivatePassword-2>
      </Private-2>
      <Public-2>
        <PublicFtpAccountId-2>44444</PublicFtpAccountId-2>
        <PublicPassword-2>test4</PublicPassword-2>
      </Public-2>
    </UserName-2>
  </Users>

Dim newxml As XElement =
  <UserName-3>
    <Private-3>
      <PrivateFtpAccountId-3>55555</PrivateFtpAccountId-3>
      <PrivatePassword-3>test5</PrivatePassword-3>
    </Private-3>
    <Public-3>
      <PublicFtpAccountId-3>66666</PublicFtpAccountId-3>
      <PublicPassword-3>test6</PublicPassword-3>
    </Public-3>
  </UserName-3>

orig.Add(newxml)
'orig.Save("FILENAMES_HERE")
```

EDIT - some ideas on how to build this at runtime.

```
    Dim theUsers As XElement = <users></users>

    ' theUsers=XElement.Load("FILE_NAME")

    Dim someIDs() As String = New String() {"1", "2", "3", "4"}
    Dim sampleUsers() As String = New String() {"lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit"}
    Dim prvtIDs() As String = New String() {"11", "12", "13", "14"}
    Dim prvtPass() As String = New String() {"p1", "p2", "p3", "p4"}
    Dim pubIDs() As String = New String() {"21", "22", "23", "24"}
    Dim pubPass() As String = New String() {"pu1", "pu2", "pu3", "pu4"}

    'add many
    For x As Integer = 0 To someIDs.Length - 1
        Dim aUser As XElement = <username uid=<%= someIDs(x) %>>
                                    <name><%= sampleUsers(x) %></name>
                                    <private>
                                        <ftpAcct>
                                            <id><%= prvtIDs(x) %></id>
                                            <password><%= prvtPass(x) %></password>
                                        </ftpAcct>
                                    </private>
                                    <public>
                                        <ftpAcct>
                                            <id><%= pubIDs(x) %></id>
                                            <password><%= pubPass(x) %></password>
                                        </ftpAcct>
                                    </public>
                                </username>
        theUsers.Add(aUser)
    Next

    'add one user
    Dim anIDs As String = "9999"
    Dim aUsernm As String = "1user"
    Dim prvtID As String = "199"
    Dim prvtPasswd As String = "prvtPass"
    Dim pubID As String = "299"
    Dim pubPasswd As String = "pubPass"

    theUsers.Add(<username uid=<%= anIDs %>>
                     <name><%= aUsernm %></name>
                     <private>
                         <ftpAcct>
                             <id><%= prvtID %></id>
                             <password><%= prvtPasswd %></password>
                         </ftpAcct>
                     </private>
                     <public>
                         <ftpAcct>
                             <id><%= pubID %></id>
                             <password><%= pubPasswd %></password>
                         </ftpAcct>
                     </public>
                 </username>)

    ' theUsers.Save("FILE_NAME")
```

I removed the aaaa-number business so that stuff like this works

```
    'find a user with an id of 3
    Dim foo As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = From bar In theUsers.Elements
                                          Where bar.@uid = "3" Select bar Take 1


    'or find user 'lorem'
    foo = From bar In theUsers.Elements
          Where bar...<name>.Value = "lorem" Select bar Take 1
```

Here is the concept as a function

```
Public Function Adduser(anID As String,
                        aUsernm As String,
                        prvtID As String,
                        prvtPassWD As String,
                        pubID As String,
                        pubPassWD As String) As XElement

    Return <username uid=<%= anID %>>
               <name><%= aUsernm %></name>
               <private>
                   <ftpAcct>
                       <id><%= prvtID %></id>
                       <password><%= prvtPassWD %></password>
                   </ftpAcct>
               </private>
               <public>
                   <ftpAcct>
                       <id><%= pubID %></id>
                       <password><%= pubPassWD %></password>
                   </ftpAcct>
               </public>
           </username>
End Function
```

It would be called like this

```
    theUsers.Add(Adduser("42", "user42", "id42", "pp42", "pubid42", "pubpass42"))
```

Comment: Thanks...this works as hard coding the values but I need this to be dynamic such that the tags will be built at runtime as well as the innertext.  I was able to most of it in my example.

Comment: @user3020047 - edited the post to show how this works dynamically.